# How to get several value in once enter ?(Number of uncertainty)

Tags: c, scanf

How can I get several values input from the keyboard (an integer type and many number of uncertainty) ?

I need to write a program which allow users to enter any number , 
Each number is delimited by the Space and when the user presses Enter, 
The number was placed in each of the variables Array.

For example,

input number: 1 2 8 9 (Enter) if input the fourth (numbers), it will  build up four variables to get that value.

number [0] = 1, number [1] = 2, number [2] = 8, number [3] = 9.

input number: 3 4 7 (Enter) if input the third (numbers), it will have to build up three variables to get that value.

number [0] = 3, number [1] = 4, number [2] = 7.

I tried to use the scan f  function,but it's not work ,

If have any good advice ,please tell me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int n, number[10];

main()
{
    printf("Enter Number of integer : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == 1) {
        printf("Enter integer : ");
        scanf("%d", &number[0]);
    } else if (n == 2) {
        printf("Enter integer : ");
        scanf("%d %d", &number[0], &number[1]);
    } else if (n == 3) {
        printf("Enter integer : ");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &number[0], &number[1], &number[2]);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried to write so far? You should paste your incomplete code in the question so that we can help you better.

Comment: @Kmeixner I'm new to this website. now I put the code in the main question. can you help me? plz

Comment: Try putting in *readable* code... i.e. format it so it makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered doing this using a combination of `scanf()`, `fgets()` and `strtok()`?

For example, you can use `scanf()` to simple query the number of inputs expected.  Then use a loop around `strtok() to tokenize user's input:

```
int main()
{
    char line[1024];
    char *token = {0};
    char delim[]={" \r\n\t"};
    long telPos = 0;
    int count, i;
    int *array = {0};

    printf("Enter Number of integers, <return> then line of integers : \n");
    scanf("%d",&count);

    getchar();//eat the newline (from <return>)

    while (fgets(line, 1024, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        array = malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
        token = strtok(line, delim);
        i = -1;
        while(token)
        {
            if((count - 1) > i++)
            {
                array[i] = atoi(token);
                token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            }
            else
            {
                for(i=0;i<count;i++) printf("value %d: %d\n", i, array[i]);
            }
        }
        //do something here with array, then free it.
        free(array);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @KaiketsuZorori - your are welcome.  Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation of scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). You can use the return value of the function to determine if reading an integer has succeeded. thus you can do something like

```
while (scanf("%d") > 0) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will read an integer one digit at a time and save to each element of number. "%1d" limits scanf to one character. With this, it is not necessary to seperate the digits with spaces.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
int n,number[10];
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter Number of integer : \n");
    if ( ( scanf("%d",&n)) == 1)
    {
        printf ( "Enter integer : \n");
        i = 0;
        while ( i < n && ( ( scanf ( "%1d", &number[i])) == 1))
        {
            printf ( "scanned %d into number[%d]\n", number[i], i);
            i++;
            if ( i >= 10)
            {
                printf ( "stopping at ten digits\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to consider that can provide a great deal of flexibility is to read the input as **characters** instead of **digits**. Especially when reading individual digits into an array. This gives you complete control to parse the input on a character-by-character basis and respond in any way you like. A quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXI 10

int main (void) {

    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int numbers[MAXI] = {0};

    printf ("\n Enter a number: ");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            numbers[n] = c - '0';
            n++;
            if (n == MAXI)
                break;
        }
    }

    printf ("\n The numbers entered are: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("%d", numbers[i]);
    printf ("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Examples**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_multi_ints <<<$( printf "01234567890\n" )

 Enter a number:
 The numbers entered are: 0123456789

$ ./bin/scanf_multi_ints <<<$( printf "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0\n" )

 Enter a number:
 The numbers entered are: 0123456789

$ ./bin/scanf_multi_ints

 Enter a number: 01234567890

 The numbers entered are: 0123456789

$ ./bin/scanf_multi_ints

 Enter a number: 01abc234dog5 6 and 7 more 8 dogs 90

 The numbers entered are: 0123456789
```

Here the numbers can be entered in any fashion. With spaces between. Without. With intervening letters or words. You get to decide. The conversion from character to digit is a simple subtraction of decimal `48` (0x30 hex).

Answer (score 1):

Using `fgets()` is best.  Yet pre-reading the leading spaces before `scanf("%d", &some_int)` can work too.  Look for a `'\n'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Scan & toss all white-space.  Return 1 on \n or EOF, else return 0
static bool EatWhiteSpaceUntilEOL(FILE *inf) {
  int ch;
  do {
    ch = fgetc(inf);
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
      return true;
  } while (isspace(ch));
  ungetc(ch, inf);
  return false;
}

// Return number of `int` read.  Set *eol true if \n or EOF encountered.  
size_t Read_int(FILE *inf, int *dest, size_t n, bool *eol) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    *eol = EatWhiteSpaceUntilEOL(inf);
    if (*eol) {
      return i;
    }
    if (fscanf(inf, "%d", &dest[i]) != 1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  *eol = EatWhiteSpaceUntilEOL(inf);
  return n;

}

int main(void) {
  int n;
  printf("Enter maximum number of `int` to read: ");
  bool eol;
  if (Read_int(stdin, &n, 1, &eol) != 1 || !eol) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int *a = calloc(n, sizeof *a);
  size_t count = Read_int(stdin, a, n, &eol);
  printf("Count:%zu First:%d Last:%i  Done:%s\n", count, a[0], a[count - 1],
      eol ? "Yes" : "No");
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```